# Smarty web site inner pages are not working

Tags: http-status-code-404

I am doing a task in a site which is done by other programmer in Smarty.

**Basic flow of my task**

1. In admin panel, the user upload a CSV file
2. Using cron the CSV file data to be stored in MySQL database. It is a Godaddy's shared hosting.

Right now the cron is executing but the data are not import. I have to fix this issue. This is the task I am working on it for last couple of days.
Note - It is not completed. I am working on it.

**Issue**

Today client sent an email that inner pages of the site is not working. But I worked only in the admin panel of the site. I am sure that I worked in admin folder. Client said the front end was worked before I start the work.

My doubt is, when I investigate the issue I got a clue.
that is home page is working fine, the menus for the homepage are loaded properly from database. only few pages are having 404 error only if it has SEF URL
i.e 
1) `http://www.example.com/category/Baseball-MLB` - is SEF url and not working, but it is working fine in URL - `http://www.example.com/category.php?arg1=Baseball-MLB`

The same type of links working for many pages and not worked for SEF urls.

I am not sure what makes this issue. I tried in forums but did not get a solution.
The site is in live so I have to fix it as soon as possible.

Comment: This issue doesn't seem Smarty related. Are you using a custom made webapp or built upon Wordpress for example? Can you access web server logs for extra info?

Comment: It seems to be related with .htaccess and mod_rewrite. Have you already solved this problem?